# Is there any way to customized or extend Admin Console UI

Tags: togglz

please let me know if anyone knows above query. I want add extra tags into index.html file for console UI Page. I have done lot of R&D, but couldn't find solution.

Comment: What kind of tags do you want to add in? You can define your own annotations and add them to your FeatureToggle enum. These annotations will be displayed on the console.

Comment: Could please any link to do that if possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to display some custom information for a given toggle on the admin console, you can do this by creating your own annotation.

See this example:
https://github.com/togglz/togglz/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/togglz/core/annotation/Owner.java

Then just mark your toggle with that annotation.

```
enum class FeatureToggle {

    @EnabledByDefault
    @Owner("Gary")
    SOME_FEATURE;

    fun isActive(): Boolean {
        return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive { name }
    }

}
```